# To compare exit-rates for two groups

Tags: r, statistics

We have 2 data-set `good` and `bad` in R. It contains `users` and `games`. 
Games contains 10 different game types `1,2,...,10`. Dataset `good` contains users that have played for long time and `bad` contains users that have played for a short time and then stopped played.

```
head(good)
user   game
1      4
2      3
3      4
1      1
15     4
1      2
```

and

```
head(bad)
user   game
10      4
22      3
37      4
37      1
38      4
46      2
```

I have found the latest game a user has played before he/she stopped playing. 
So for one group for a fixed game we have the times it have been 'last-game played' / total time it has been played.
This gives us an exit-rate. If the exit-rate is high it simply means that it's likely to be the latest game played and if the exit-rate is low it means that it's likely that the game is not the last game played.

In R we can see the exit-rate for the group `good`

```
exitrate_good
game  exitrate
1     0.133333
2     0.127772
3     0.090332
...
9     0.317307
10    0.190854
```

And similar for the other group `bad`

```
exitrate_bad
game  exitrate
1     0.186522
2     0.045888
3     0.192556
...
9     0.365899
10    0.119331
```

Here we can for example see that game 9 has a high exit rate in both `good` and `bad`.

My question is: How should one find the game that is not popular and causes players to stop playing ?

A game that has been played the last time for a user could cause that the user stops playing. How should I compare the exit-rate for the two groups?

------- (extended)

Lets look at group `good`.
In R I type `last_game_good` and we get this output

```
latest_game_played   not_latest_game_played
734                  3917
645                  3507
...
765                  2100
112                  535
```

So the first line simply say `734+3917` has played this game, where it was the latest game played in `734` cases.

Here we can also see that game id 9 (the second last line) has a very high `latest_game_played` compared to `not_latest_game_played`. For this I use `pairwise.prop.test` and I get all the pairwise correlations, some have low p-value and some have p-value higher than 0.05. How can I use this information and how can I compare it if I run the same thing for other groups, say group `bad` ?

Comment: Your 1st question is (more) general and it doesn't really need 2 different datasets (good/bad), but one dataset (users). The second one is more reasonable in your case as you want to investigate separately for good/bad users. So, as you said game 9 has a high exit rate (you can describe it as not popular(?)), but it's even worse for bad users. You'd probably need pairwise comparisons of games within good/bad users. Also, be careful when you interpret results using the "causality" term. Usually it's a big thing to say, as a pattern has to do with correlation, but not always with causality.

Comment: Additionally, for percentages' comparisons you need the number of successes, number of failures (or totals), otherwise you'll try to statistically compare two numbers (the actual percentages) and it's not possible. Check this : https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/stats/html/pairwise.prop.test.html

Comment: I have updated the question. I have made a table containing number of successes and totals but I'm still not sure how to use it to compare groups.

Comment: Hope my answer (one of the things you could do) is helpful. Keep in mind that, as I said in my post, you can investigate lots of different things with this dataset. It's a better and more secure practice to have in mind exactly what you want to investigate/discover and then build the dataset (or your experiment), otherwise you'll get frustrated and lost within the options you have.

Comment: Thanks for the response. My goal is to find games that 'causes' users stop playing games. (I want to remove these games so users might continue playing rather than stop playing). Perhaps I should use some exp designs for this purpose.

Comment: You should 100% get some insights from this analysis and then go back and implement your "improved gaming experience" version by removing those games. Then you can randomly select some users to experience the improved version, the rest of the users experience the old (AB test) and see what happens to the general exit rate, or number of minutes played, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, one thing you can do is comparing differences between games among your groups. Eg. Does game X have a higher exit rate compared to game Y within the good group? What about the bad group? Is it the same pattern? Maybe completely different pattern?

Another thing you can do is compare games to themselves in different groups. Eg. Does game X in good group have a higher exit rate than game X in bad group?

A third thing is to pre-specify and fix an exit rate that is bad for you and compare all games in all groups with that. Eg. I know that an exit rate of 40% is bad for me. Are there any games in any group that have a higher exit rate than 40%?

I'll focus on the 1st case.

I create the dataset like this

```
dt = read.table(text=
"latest_game_played   not_latest_game_played
734                  3917
645                  3507
765                  2100
112                  535", header=T)

# create game id
dt$game_id = c(1,2,9,10)

# create total numbers
dt$totals = dt$latest_game_played + dt$not_latest_game_played

dt

#   latest_game_played not_latest_game_played game_id totals
# 1                734                   3917       1   4651
# 2                645                   3507       2   4152
# 3                765                   2100       9   2865
# 4                112                    535      10    647
```

Then I calculate the percentages and check if there's at least one statistically significant difference

```
# check percentages
prop.test(dt$latest_game_played, dt$totals)

# 4-sample test for equality of proportions without continuity correction
# 
# data:  dt$latest_game_played out of dt$totals
# X-squared = 176.51, df = 3, p-value < 2.2e-16
# alternative hypothesis: two.sided
# sample estimates:
#    prop 1    prop 2    prop 3    prop 4 
# 0.1578155 0.1553468 0.2670157 0.1731066
```

Note that you can also save those percentages in a new column you can create yourself. The p-value you see there is less than `0.05` so there's at least one game with a higher exit rate than another one. Or, in other words, it's reasonable to go and check pairwise differences/comparisons. No idea (yet) which difference is statistically significant, or if more of them exist. The next step is to go and find out.

```
# check pairwise comparisons
pairwise.prop.test(dt$latest_game_played, dt$totals)

# Pairwise comparisons using Pairwise comparison of proportions 
# 
# data:  dt$latest_game_played out of dt$totals 
# 
#      1       2       3      
# 2 0.82    -       -      
# 3 < 2e-16 < 2e-16 -      
# 4 0.82    0.82    3.2e-06
# 
# P value adjustment method: holm
```

This is a table of pairwise p-values. You can see that game 9 (prop 3) is statistically significantly higher than all other percentages. No difference between the exit rates of the other games.

You can do a similar process for your other group and see if you find the same thing/pattern

Comment: In my case I do a pairwise.prop.test in my group as well and I get that game 9 has all p-values below 0.05. This must mean that game 9 has an impact that the prop.test has low p-value ? Other pairwise p-values are more sporadically for other gamepairs so it would make sense to make a new table where I have removed game 9 and then compare the new set with the old one ?

Comment: Finding the same pattern in the bad group means that game 9 has a high/bad exit rate no matter if user is good or bad. That's the insight you get from the analysis. What you can do now is to start an experiment where you have some users play all games and some users play all games apart from game 9. Then compare the average exit rates to see what happens in real life. If you just remove game 9 from the data you already have it's just a theoretical approximation of the real situation. You don't know if by removing game 9 all other games will have the same exit rates. This is just an assumption.

Comment: Say I have 3 of the 10 games with very low p-value. What should be the next step for analyse this further? So far a low p-value for the 3 games just saying that there is a difference in the two groups for these 3 game.

Comment: So, you managed to find 3 games where the statistical comparison between the two groups (within each game) is statistically significant. You can see which group performs better for each game (so far you just classified that difference as stat. sign.) and then you can calculate the observed power of your comparison (shows how confident you are that this is indeed a stat. sign. difference).